# Is the notion of Chudail (चुड़ैल) and Daayan (डायन) based on any scripture?

Tags: belief, supernatural-races, demon, supernatural

Both - Chudail/Chuṛail (चुड़ैल), and  Daayan/Ḍāin (डायन) are mass popular terms across the Indian subcontinent. Both of them are believed to be supernatural entities having the appearance of a Women, generally conceived to have negative connotations. In fact, in the popular mass vernacular its not uncommon to see both words being used against females who are thought to be inauspicious and malevolent. Perhaps an equivalent counterpart to the Western concept of Witch.

---

**Question:**

**Is the concept of Chudail (चुड़ैल) & Daayan (डायन), explicitly mentioned in any of our canonical texts?**

If yes, are both of these entities mentioned to be inauspicious and "demonic" in their nature and character? Does scriptures give guidelines as to - How to recognize them and what are the remedies to be safe against/from them, or how to get rid of them (i.e., to kill or destroy them)?

Comment: Dayan is the Hindi Tadbhava for Dakini which do find mention in scriptures (which I don’t know)

Comment: Wow @Proxy , I'm actually a bit afraid of the term "Bhoot-Vidya" though. But, perhaps maybe an intersting subject. ;)

Comment: Yes, @Archit ; The *Tatsama* => *Tatbhava* game is aa given. I'd be more interested if direct reference were to be found or perhaps in some commentaries, which might explain how or when did *dakini* become *daayan*. ;)

Comment: @Vivikta ,You had asked a similar question on “sahaja kulaja...”,dakini and daayan are apparently related,so there’s that.I’m blank about Chudail,if you ask on scriptural basis.But,[this video is made by a person who researches on these practices,and his facts were found to be correct,it gives more info on these species](https://youtu.be/k2TsnOEgwQ8)

Comment: @Vivikta Ah,yes.My old mistake.Thanks for letting me know.!